# ¿Cómo puedo cargar una imagen a un perfil?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, css

explico: a la hora de registrarte te pide una imagen, pero la cuestión es como hago que al iniciar sesion tambien se cargue dicha imagen de ese usuario para colocarlar como foto de perfil.

El siguiente es mi control de iniciar sesion.
**control.php**

```
<?php
ESTE ES MI ARCHIVO QUE HACE  LA CONEXION
    require('conectar.php');
    
    session_start();
    // Verificamos si la variable esta definida
    if(isset($_SESSION["id_usuario"])){
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
ESTO LO PUSE POR QUE AQUI VERIFICO QUE SEA LA MISMA CONTRASEÑA Y EL MISMO USUARIO QUE AL REGISTRARSE PUSO LA PERSONA    
    if(!empty($_POST))
    {
        $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $error = '';
        
        
        //$sha1_pass = sha1($password);
        
        $sql = "SELECT Id_usuario, NOMBRE, Domicilio, Telefono, USUARIO, FOTO, Email, Password, usuarios.id_tipo_usuario, Nom_tipo_usuario FROM Usuarios JOIN Tipo_Usuario ON Usuarios.id_tipo_usuario = Tipo_Usuario.Id_tipo_usuario WHERE USUARIO = '$usuario' AND Password = '$password'";
        $resultado = $Conexion->query($sql);
        $rows = $resultado->rowCount();
        
        if($rows > 0) {
            $row = $resultado->fetch();
            $_SESSION['Id_usuario'] = $row['Id_usuario'];
            $_SESSION['id_tipo_usuario'] = $row['id_tipo_usuario'];
            $_SESSION['USUARIO'] = $row['USUARIO'];
            $_SESSION['NOMBRE'] = $row['NOMBRE'];
            $_SESSION['Nom_tipo_usuario'] = $row['Nom_tipo_usuario'];
ES ESTE TENGO DUDA SI VA ESA VARIABLE O VA FILES PUES SE TRATA DE UN ARCHIVO
            $_SESSION['FOTO'] = $row['FOTO'];

            if ($row['id_tipo_usuario']===TU4) {
                header("location:cliente/bienvenido1.php");
            }
        }else{
            echo '<script language="javascript">alert("USUARIO O PASSWORD INCORRECTOS, INTENTELO NUEVAMENTE");window.location.href="iniciar_sesion.php"</script>';
        }
    }
    
?>
```

lo siguiente es a donde quiero que se muestre es decir el perfil
EN ESTE ARCHIVO SI ME MUESTRA EL NOMBRE Y EL NOMBRE DEL TIPO DE USUARIO, PERO LA FOTO NO ME LA CARGA SOLO ME APARECE UN RECUADRO VACIO
**bienvenido1.php**

```
<?php
  require ('../conectar.php');
  session_start();
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" >
    </head>
    <body>
    <header class="header">
ESTE SI CARGA
      <a class="navbar-brand"><p>Hola:<?php echo $_SESSION['NOMBRE'];?></p></a>
      
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only"></span></a>
          

        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Buscar Producto" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Buscar Producto</button>
        </form>
        <p class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" style="text-align: right; float: right;"><a href="../logout.php">Cerrar Sesion</a></p>
      </div>

    </nav>

  </header>
  <div class="container">
    <fieldset>
      <p>Nuestras promociones</p>
ESTE TAMBIEN CARGA
      <p>Eres nuestro: <b><?php echo $_SESSION['Nom_tipo_usuario'];?></b> favorito</p>
ESTE ES EL PROBLEMA, SI SIRVE DE ALGO LAS IMAGENES CARGADAS ESTAN EN MI CARPETA LLAMADA images
    <img src="<?php echo $_SESSION['FOTO'];?>" width="50">
     

    </fieldset>
  </div>
  <footer>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 text-left">
            <h6 class="text-muted lead">CONTACTO:</h6>
            <h6 class="text-muted">
            Camino a San Luis del Pino<br>
            Km 3.5 Zinacatepec, Puebla.<br>
            
            </h6>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 text-right">
            <h6 class="text-muted lead">ENCUENTRANOS EN LAS REDES</h6>
            <div class="redes-footer">
              <a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><img src="imagenes/facebook-2.png"></a>
              <a href="https://twitter.com/"><img src="imagenes/twitter-2.png"></a>
              <a href="https://www.youtube.com/"><img src="imagenes/youtube-2.png"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
</footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

MI ARCHIVO DEL PERFIL ES DECIR bienvenido1.php ESTA DENTRO DE LA CARPETA CLIENTES AL IGUAL QUE CONECTAR.PHP

Comment: @masterguru no sale ni el nombre, ya lo puse tal como me lo pones y nada

Comment: haciendo eso si me aparece asi [FOTO] => images/WIN_20211113_23_35_59_Pro.jpg pero sigue sin aparecerme nada

Comment: @masterguru si me refiero a que es el nombre de la imagen

Comment: @masterguru no me sale aun, en mi primer archivo de control.php si va foto con la variable row? y no se le debe aumenta img src?

Comment: @masterguru si me aparece  [FOTO] => images/WIN_20211113_23_35_59_Pro.jpg

Comment: @masterguru me sale Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: En qué ruta están guardadas las fotos?

Comment: @GiancarloVentura estan guardadas en la carpeta images